# How to create a read-only user in Azure PostgreSQL?

Tags: azure, postgresql

How can I create a read-only user in Azure PostgreSQL?

On my local postgres installation, I can run these commands to create a read-only user:

```
  CREATE USER spqr1 WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'password';
  REVOKE CONNECT ON DATABASE postgres FROM PUBLIC;
  CREATE DATABASE mydb;
  REVOKE CONNECT ON DATABASE mydb FROM PUBLIC;
  GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE mydb TO spqr1;
  \connect mydb
  REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON SCHEMA public FROM PUBLIC;
  GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA public TO spqr1;
```

When I run these commands on an Azure PostgreSQL database, the new user `spqr1` has privileges that I don't want: they can connect to the `postgres` database, and create tables in `mydb`. On my local machine, the new user doesn't have these privileges.

It looks to me like there is a default user `azure_superadmin` who has granted `PUBLIC` the privilege of connecting to the `postgres` database, and the privilege of creating tables in any public schema. My admin account (`meadmin`) didn't grant those privileges, and can't remove them. Is this what's going on, and if so then how should I create a read-only account?

Here is the trimmed output from `\l`:

```
   Name    |      Owner      |      Access privileges          
-----------+-----------------+-------------------------------------
 mydb      | meadmin         | =T/meadmin                         +
           |                 | meadmin=CTc/meadmin                +
           |                 | spqr1=c/meadmin
 postgres  | azure_superuser | =Tc/azure_superuser                +
           |                 | azure_superuser=CTc/azure_superuser
 template0 | azure_superuser | =c/azure_superuser                 +
           |                 | azure_superuser=CTc/azure_superuser
 template1 | azure_superuser | =c/azure_superuser                 +
           |                 | azure_superuser=CTc/azure_superuser
```

And here is the trimmed output from `\dn+`, after I have connected to `mydb`:

```
  Name  |      Owner      |         Access privileges        
--------+-----------------+------------------------------------
 public | azure_superuser | azure_superuser=UC/azure_superuser+
        |                 | =UC/azure_superuser
```

Answer (score 2):

I was having a lot of trouble with this too but I finally got it working. Here's what I did:

1. Create new role, `readonly`

   ```
   CREATE ROLE readonly WITH LOGIN PASSWORD 'password';
   ```
2. Grant connect on database

   ```
   GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE databasename to readonly;
   ```
3. Connect to [databasename] on local database cluster

   ```
   \c databasename
   ```
4. Grant Usage to schemas

   ```
   GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA schema_name TO readonly;
   ```
5. Grant SELECT access to all current and future tables

   ```
   ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA schema_name GRANT SELECT ON TABLES to readonly;
   ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA schema_name GRANT ALL ON TABLES TO readonly;

   GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA schema_name TO readonly;
   GRANT SELECT ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA schema_name TO readonly;
   ```

Note that as far as I know, you won't be able to create a read only user for future schemas that are created as well. I think you will have to grant the select privileges again if a new schema is created. Also note that the one thing that really tripped me up was that the `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES` and `GRANT SELECT ON ALL...` statements only worked when I was logged in as the owner of those schemas. When I was not logged in as an owner of those schemas when I ran those commands there were no error messages or anything but then the `readonly` user still didn't have sufficient access. Hope this helps!

Comment: my database name was `postgres` and my schema_name was `public`